# Jquery toggleclass in separate divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the js from bootstrap to do a div collapse on a Wordpress gallery page but I can't get the toggle function to work. When you click on another item, the first item doesn't collapse. It stays open. You can see it the link to the dev site: [Dev site link](http://tinyurl.com/n83n4dc)

I'm not using the accordion bootstrap setup as I wanted each collapsing div to occupy the same space below the row of triggering links.

I've asked this question from a bootstrap point of view but got no answers. So I'm wondering if there's a way of doing it using Jquery toggleclass?

Bootstrap applies the class 'in' to the expanded item. So I guess I'd need to have toggle class remove that? I found and tried to adapt some Jquery but no luck.

A simplified version of the code is:

```
<div id="desktop-view">

    <div id="gallery-squares-1" class="gallery-squares clearfix">
        <a href="#collapseExample-1" class="ie-bgsize gallery-img" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#desktop-view">
            <div class="img-mouse-over"></div>
        </a><!-- .post-gallery-img -->
        <a href="#collapseExample-2" class="ie-bgsize gallery-img" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#desktop-view">
            <div class="img-mouse-over"></div>
        </a><!-- .post-gallery-img -->
        <a href="#collapseExample-3" class="ie-bgsize gallery-img" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#desktop-view">
            <div class="img-mouse-over"></div>
        </a><!-- .post-gallery-img -->
    </div> <!-- .gallery-squares -->

    <div id="gallery-expanders-1" class="gallery-expanders clearfix">
        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-1">
            <div class="gallery-content">
                <div class="ie-bgsize gallery-content-img"></div>
                <h6>Title</h6>
                <p>Description</p>
            </div> <!-- .gallery-content -->
        </div> <!-- .collapse -->
        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-2">
            <div class="gallery-content">
                <div class="ie-bgsize gallery-content-img"></div>
                <h6>Title</h6>
                <p>Description</p>
            </div> <!-- .gallery-content -->
        </div> <!-- .collapse -->
        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-3">
            <div class="gallery-content">
                <div class="ie-bgsize gallery-content-img"></div>
                <h6>Title</h6>
                <p>Description</p>
            </div> <!-- .gallery-content -->
        </div> <!-- .collapse -->
    </div> <!-- .gallery-expanders -->

</div>
```

CSS:

```
a.gallery-img {
    width: 15%;
    padding-bottom: 15%;
    margin: 0 1.6666666% 1.6666666% 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.gallery-content {
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 1.6666666%;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1.6666666%;
}

.gallery-content-img {
    width: 98.5%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 1.8%;
}

.gallery-content h6 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    margin: 0;
    width: 98.5%;
}

.gallery-content p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    margin: 1% 0;
    width: 98.5%;
}

.gallery-content p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.img-mouse-over {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: none;
}

.img-mouse-over:hover,
.img-mouse-over:active {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) no-repeat center center;
}
```

JQuery I tried:

```
$('.gallery-squares a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.collapse').removeClass('in');
});
```

I just can't get it to remove the active class on 'in'. I guess I'd also need to make sure it only removed the 'in' from the current active div and not the one that the click will create?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll have to remove the `in` class and add the `collapse` class.

```
$(document).on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('.in').addClass('collapse').removeClass('in');
})
```

Comment: This worked great and makes sense even to me, a JS luddite! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so if we never want the `in` class there...

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('.in').removeClass('in');
})
```

or possibly on the 'show event:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('.in').removeClass('in');
})
```

(I'm not sure which one since I don't know when it adds the class `in`)

See the docs for the [collapse events here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events)